# Route query is undefined when using useRoute() in setup() for Vue3 and vue-router4(next)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router4

I am using Vue3 with vue-router 4.0.5 and I am experiencing an issue where useRoute() appears to retieve the route correctly but the query of the route is undefined, even though a query exists.

For the path `/search?q=vue` is it expected that `searchQuery` equals `vue` but it returns undefined.

In the template, `{{ $route.query.q }}` correctly returns the query value.

```js
import { useRoute } from "vue-router"

export default {
  name: "Search",
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    const searchQuery = route.query.q

    console.log(route)
    console.log(searchQuery)

    return {
      searchQuery
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ $route.query.q }}</div>
</template>
```

When logging to the console, the `route` object is logged correctly and contains the route's query object but `searchQuery` is undefined.

I am wondering why `searchQuery` is returning as undefined in this example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `route` is updated asynchronously, and you're logging it before the update actually occurs.

When you `console.log` an object, the browser automatically updates the logged value to show the latest. However, this is not true for strings, which is the reason the `searchQuery` string is `undefined` in the log, while the `route` object is up to date.

In this case, you should use a [`computed` prop](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed) to get the query. And if you want to observe the changes to the query, use a [watch](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch):

```js
import { computed, watch } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    const searchQuery = computed(() => route.query.q)

    watch(searchQuery, newSearchQuery => console.log(newSearchQuery))

    return {
      searchQuery
    }
  }
}
```